# Image spanning multiple pages

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2007

In Word (2007), is there an option that allows an image to be split, so it could span multiple pages?

The width of the image is not the problem, it is just too long.

According to what I found via a Google search; in 2008 someone said it was not possible, but I'm hoping someone has come up with a solution since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. An object in Word (characters, text boxes, images, drawings, OLE objects such as embedded charts from Excel or PDFs, ...) can only ever be on a single page. So you have to split up the image for pagination.

Heck, LaTeX treats things the same, for all that it's worth. If a word processor would have this feature it would have to treat the pages as one large contiguous layout canvas, just with page breaks in between. And page headers/footers/margins.

The only place where I think this *might* exist would be DTP programs like InDesign or Quark Express because magazines and some image-heavy books often lay out a large image on two facing sides.

Comment: Also, a printed HTML document containing the "long" object may, depending on printer (such as PDF printing feature of Mac OS X), output desired result - e.g. where the object is paginated together with the rest of the document.